# a cup spilled over a Paris dress

Tags: meaning-in-context

“Not a day passed without water making its presence felt. But in the end that presence amounted to no more than **a cup spilled over a Paris dress** after the anniversary ball given by the Governor of the Colony.”

This part is from the short story 'Journey to the source' by Alejo Carpentier. Can anyone explain the meaning of 'a cup spilled over a Paris dress' in this context?